# Wordpress Theme Update without deleting destination folder

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am using the script written by Jeremy Clark for updating my self hosted Wordpress Themes. The script can be downloaded from here - [GitHub](https://github.com/jeremyclark13/automatic-theme-plugin-update)

The updator works perfectly fine but it deletes the destination theme folder and then
unzips the updates from the downloaded zip file. This deletes the customizations like custom.css

**My Question:**

Is there any way that i can overwrite the updates by not delete the existing (old)theme data.
This way if my theme size is 12mb, then i can just zip the new updates(only the updated files) which will be merely 200kb (depending on updates). This way i can retain the customizations.

Any thoughts on this ?

I hope i was able to explain my problem.

--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this in the below way:

```
add_filter('upgrader_pre_install', 'backup', 10, 2); //line 1
add_filter('upgrader_post_install', 'recover', 10, 2); //line2
add_filter('pre_set_site_transient_update_themes', 'check_for_update'); //line 3
```

**Explaination**

**upgrader_pre_install** is a filter hook which runs just before the upgrade starts.

**upgrader_post_install** is a filter hooks which runs just after the upgradation has finished.

So the below functions get triggered at the appropriate time which allows me to take a backup of customized files and then later copies them back into the theme.

```
function backup() {

     //create a folder using mkdir outside the theme folder and copy the necessary files.

}

function restore() {

     //restore the files and then delete the backup folder

}
```

Hope this helps to developers in similar situation.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you're doing it wrong. WordPress has [child themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) just because parent themes get updated and you'll lose all modifications in that process.

For this same reason, you shouldn't modify core files or plugin files.

Comment: Yes, child themes is the way to do that. +1 on that. But my requirement is to update the parent theme. I am trying to extend the upgrade class of Wordpress to achieve that.

Comment: You can use your current theme as a child theme and delete the files you haven’t modified. Don’t forget to install the original parent theme too. Not tested, but it should do the job.

Comment: Thanks @RRikesh for your feedback. Will keep your suggestion in mind.